# Jquery, Jcarousellite_1.0.1 is not working why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to do a basic jquery to a photo gallery, i want to have some images and two buttons to show next images and previous images.
Im trying to do it with jcarousellite but nothing happens but i guess everything is ok!

This is my jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js"></script>


   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#images").jCarouselLite({
              btnNext: "#prevBTN",
              btnPrev: "#nextBTN",
              visible: 1
            })
        });

    </script>
```

This is my html code:

```
 <div id="mainCenterContainer">


  <h1>Design<span>Gallery</span></h1>

  <div class="fr" id="nextBTN"><img src="images/nexticon.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Next" title="Next">  </div>
  <div class="fr" id="prevBTN"><img src="images/previousbutton.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Back" title="Back"></div>

<div class="cr"></div>
     <div id="images">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="Image" title="Image 1"</a>
                <img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="Image" title="Image 2"</a>
                <img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="Projecto Image" title="Image 3"</a>
                <img class="removeMargin" src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="Image" title="Projecto 4"</a>
                <img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="Projecto Image" title="Image 5"</a>
                <img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="Projecto Image" title="Image 6"</a>
                <img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="Projecto Image" title="Image"</a>
                <img class="removeMargin" src="imagens/pic4.jpg" alt="Image" title="Projecto 8"</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="Image" title="Image 1"</a>
                <img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="Image" title="Image 2"</a>
                <img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="Image" title="Image 3 "</a>
                <img class="removeMargin" src="imagens/pic4.jpg" alt="Image" title="Image"</a>
                <img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="Image" title="Image"</a>
                <img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="Image" title="Image "</a>
                <img src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="Image" title="Image "</a>
                <img class="removeMargin" src="images/pic4.jpg" alt="Image" title="Image"</a>
            </li>
         </ul> 


 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, its because when we need to use many jquery functions i guess we need to do the appropriate import, in my example the
`<script type="text/javascript" src="jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js">&lt;/script>` before our function that needs this import!And i was doing this import before other function.
Now i put this import before the function that i want do the slide and it works.
Thanks!